# Bootstrap menu integration with WordPress

Tags: wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to convert my bootstrap menu to WP theme but I am confused with few things here.

my bootstrap code is

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
        </div>
        <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                        <li class="active"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">Blog</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">about</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">contact</a></li>
```

and for while converting to WP i am using following function

```
<?php wp_nav_menu(array ('theme-location' => 'primary' 'container' => '' 'container_class' => '' 'menu_class' '' =>) ); ?>
```

can Anybody explain or tell  me what will be my 
container 
container_class and 
menu_class

thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to override Walker_Nav_Menu  class visit this [wp_bootstrap_navwalker](https://github.com/twittem/wp-bootstrap-navwalker/blob/master/wp_bootstrap_navwalker.php) , use this in your functions.php file or include this class in your functions.php , this extends default Walker_Nav_Menu  class and  will override your  wordpress default Walker_Nav_Menu class what you need to do extra is replace default walker with bootstrap walker in your wp_nav_menu argument array like below code.

```
<?php

$defaults = array(
    'theme_location'  => '',
    'menu'            => '',
    'container'       => 'div',
    'container_class' => '',
    'container_id'    => '',
    'menu_class'      => 'menu',
    'menu_id'         => '',
    'echo'            => true,
    'fallback_cb'     => 'wp_page_menu',
    'before'          => '',
    'after'           => '',
    'link_before'     => '',
    'link_after'      => '',
    'items_wrap'      => '<ul id="%1$s" class="%2$s">%3$s</ul>',
    'depth'           => 0,
    'walker'          => 'wp_bootstrap_navwalker' // here you override your Walker_Nav_Menu   class
);

wp_nav_menu( $defaults );

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Its always better to use the menu walker class, as it gives you more control over the menu (which usually are quite tricky). But for a quick fix you can use it the traditional way as well.

Container usually is a wrapper outside the ul, and container-class is the name of the class that is assigned to this div. Similarly menu-class is the class that is given to the ul. Now considering that you have a registered primary-menu, the code in your case should be

```
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top">
          <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
              <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              </button>
            </div>

    <?php 
    wp_nav_menu(
        array (
            'theme-location' => 'primary',
            'container' => 'div',
            'container_class' => 'navbar-collapse collapse',
            'container_id'    => 'navbar',
            'menu_class' => 'nav navbar-nav'
       ) 
    ); 
?>
</div>
</nav>
```